# Using WP web scraper with WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to use WP Web Scraper plugin with WP in my site www.eastwickpark.co.uk to get online ratings of the practice from another site

https://www.iwantgreatcare.org/gpsurgeries/eastwick-park-medical-practice

I used this code snippet

```
<img src="http://www.eastwickpark.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/iwantgreatcarelogo.png" />
<div>
[wpws url="https://www.iwantgreatcare.org/gpsurgeries/eastwick-park-medical-practice" query=".image-middle" basehref="1" ]
</div>
```

Then I used custom CSS in the themes stylesheet editor

```
.btn.blue,
div .btn.blue {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}

/*** Stars ***/
.sprite-icons.star-blue-outline {
    background-image: url('http://www.eastwickpark.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/star-blue-outline.png');
    width: 19px;
    height: 17px;
}

.sprite-icons.star-blue-fill {
    background-image: url('http://www.eastwickpark.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/star-blue.png');
    width: 19px;
    height: 17px;
}

.sprite-icons.star-blue-half {
    background-image: url('http://www.eastwickpark.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/star-blue-half.png');
    width: 19px;
    height: 17px;
}

.sprite-icons.caret-white {
    background-image: url('http://www.eastwickpark.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/caret-white.png');
    width: 10px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

I've got a problem with my CSS  in that the button "wraps".

Tried to just get the star rating targeting the class "raty-rating-wrapper-readonly" part but then I get a whole load of vertical stars.

i.e. if i use

```
[wpws url="https://www.iwantgreatcare.org/gpsurgeries/eastwick-park-medical-practice" query=".raty-rating-wrapper-readonly" basehref="1" ]
```

[image: Screenshot]

I get a whole vertical list of 5 * images?

If I use image-middle div like this

```
[wpws url="https://www.iwantgreatcare.org/gpsurgeries/eastwick-park-medical-practice" query=".image-middle" basehref="1" ]
```

I get a weird wrap on the button.

[image]

Can't figure this out, and have to admit I'm not a CSS guru. Any insight would be gratefully received.

Comment: Isn't it easier just to embed the review widget supplied by http://www.eastwickpark.co.uk?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you mean here. The intention is to show the rating of an external review site in our site eastwickpark.co.uk rather than run our own review process.

Comment: Screen shots added showing  the button "wrap" problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean your homepage, but iwantgreatcarw.org site. They have [widget](https://iwantgreatcare.zendesk.com/entries/60155315-Can-I-link-to-my-surgery-profile-page-from-my-practice-website-) that you can include in your site

Comment: You can fix the wrapping with `#widgets .textwidget a { display: inline-block } or inline-flex`. Plus there is a `br` tag above the text and maybe that is dynamic. It is causing the extra space above. My bad! All this time I was looking up the page from where the reviews came in.

Comment: @agustin Ah! now I get you. I hadn't seen that.

Comment: @Manoj thanks, that gets me there, and the br was styled, so set it to display none.@agustin, yours was the "lateral" / sensible approach

Comment: @manoj kumar, do you want to post this as an answe, hate to see rep go to waste

Comment: Hmmm. It was worth of a comment but since you hate to see it, I will add some explanation to the answer and elongate it. Just a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've got a problem with my CSS in that the button "wraps"

The cause of the wrapping behaviour is due to `<br>` tag dynamically generated by WordPress. You can either fix it by following the guideline here: [Stop WordPress automatically adding `<br>` tags to post content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content)

The above post is a plus for you because it also removes the `<p>` tags that are dynamically generated. I just browsed through your code and found a lot of unwanted p tags.

> Can't figure this out, and have to admit I'm not a CSS guru. Any
>   insight would be gratefully received.

Since you hinted for a CSS solution, a simple fix is to hide the br tags using `#widgets .textwidget br { display: none; }`. Alternatively `#widgets .textwidget a { display: inline-flex; align-items: center }` fixes the space and aligns the arrow image as the br tag is ignored inside and initial direction of flex is `row`.

**Unwrapped button:**

[image]